# Intel XDK app framework slider length

Tags: intel-xdk, appframework

How can I make a slider wider? I have text in the toggle slider "Graph" or "Table" which gets cut off. How can I extend it.

Here's the relevant element:

```
<div class="wide-control">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="ModeSwitch">
<label for="ModeSwitch" data-off="Graph" data-on="Table"><span></span>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to change the width in the Intel XDK UI. This is a set with for this widget as far as I know. You can override the css style in your own index.html file below (I added 100 to each width but you can adjust as you see fit):

```
<style type="text/css">
        #afui input.toggle+label {width: 165px;}
        #afui input.toggle:checked+label>span {
            transform: translate3d(137px,0,0);
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(137px,0,0);
        }
</style>
```

Note: Make sure this style tag comes after the afui.css loaded in your index.html file.